# Which Python extension for Windows GUI automation offers the most flexibility for tackling poorly designed UIs?

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, automation

I have a horribly complicated (and very poorly designed) autodialer application I need to automate to make it possible for some less technical users to contact customers.

I would like to try using Python to accomplish this, and was wondering what experiences people have had with this. Poking around I've found a few extensions geared towards this type of thing:

- [Python Win32 GUI Automation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywinauto/) (EDIT: PyWinAuto is [hosted on GitHub](http://pywinauto.github.io/) now)
- [WATSUP](http://www.tizmoi.net/watsup/intro.html)
- [winGuiAuto](http://www.brunningonline.net/simon/blog/archives/winGuiAuto.py.html)

I would like to compile the end product into a standalone executable, so I'm looking for an extension that plays nice with pyinstaller, but is flexible enough to tackle this application with lots of tabs, checkboxes, radio buttons and buried options- and also refuses to save it's settings properly on close :(  The system is running Windows 7.

Has anyone out there tried this sort of thing and could indicate which one could handle these requirements?

(Compatible with pyinstaller and Windows 7, and can handle drilling down to checkboxes, radio buttons etc.)

Comment: Are you interested only in Python backed solution?

Comment: I would prefer a Python solution, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyWinauto should be able to handle it.  I used it for automating a OpenGL video game that had buttons and the like that are not Windows widgets so I had to use mouse clicks.  However with your app you should be able to drill into the widgets with the functions it provides for using windows widgets.  I recommend if possible to have pywinauto actually launch the dialer as it can be harder to find the correct name of the running app if you don't.

If the app does not use windows gui widgets then you will be able to have it click on the apps window to automate things.  One thing you will find is the app must be visible and in focus.  So if you want your app to be user interactive you will have to place a window in proximity to the dialer that has buttons.  You will have to train your people not to click the autodialer window.

Comment: I've been quite happy with PyWinAuto.  It works perfectly with PyInstaller and no problems with Window 7.  My only complaints: are that it can be tedious sometimes to identify a particular window control if there are many with similar names, and it can't retrieve text from all widget types... but for my purposes it has worked well.

Comment: If you could tell us the name of the Auto Dialer program (if not custom) then if people search for that program name then they will find this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about python, but project Sikuli sonuds great for what you want to do. It's a python project with image recognition -> http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1074469